# How to find a dominant term?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, asymptotics

In order to understand an optical communication channel I need to find the dominat term of this

$$
\frac{1}{n}\log\left(\sum_{q=0}^{\lceil\frac{n}{d+1}\rceil}\binom{n-(q-1)d}{q}\right),
$$
where $d$ is a fixed positive integer.

using the Stirling formula $k!\sim \left(\frac{k}{e}\right)^k\sqrt{2\pi k}$ and this $\binom{n}{k}\sim\frac{n^k}{k!}$ I get this:

$$
\frac{1}{n}\log\left(\sum_{q=0}^{\lceil\frac{n}{d+1}\rceil}\frac{(e(n-(q-1)d))^q}{q^q\sqrt{2\pi q}}\right),
$$

But I still have no idea of how to get the dominant terms.

Comment: The largest value of ${n \choose k}$ for fixed $n$ is achieved at $k=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$. This might get you an idea of what type of term are you looking for, because you have to take into account the contribution of other small terms.

Comment: What is the domain for $n$ and $d$? Can we assume $n$ large? Larger than $d$?

Comment: @N74 Yes, $d$ is a fixed positive integer while $n\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: @Tal-Botvinnik And that holds when $n$ is getting larger and larger?

Comment: Yes, they are Pascal's triangle coefficients

Comment: @Tal-Botvinnik But if $n\rightarrow\infty$ the term in $q=\lfloor \frac{N}{2}\rfloor$ where $N=\lceil\frac{n}{d+1}\rceil$ will tends to infinity as well and at the same speed since $d$ is a fixed number... So I will end with an expression like $\frac{e^n(n-n)^n}{n^n\sqrt{n}}$ where everything is going to infinity!

Comment: OP is looking for the dominant term. So I was just pointing out the dominant term inside the summation.

Comment: I don´t understand

Comment: Perhaps clarify us what are you looking for. What do you mean by dominant term? I understood you are looking for the first term in the asymptotic expansion.

Comment: @Tal-Botvinnik 
I want to find the term which gets the biggest when $n$ gets bigger, in  order to say my expression is in some way something plus $O($that term$)$.